# Python - Appending of two Tif files into specific file

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, tiff

Python - Appending of two `TIF` files into specific file

My requirement is to append two one pager `TIF` file into single `TIF` file with two pages. I know there exists append_images parameter and tried implementing it as follows:

```
img1 = Image.open(open("file1.tif", 'rb'))
img2 = Image.open(open(“file2.tif", 'rb'))
img1.seek(0)
img1.save(output.tif,save_all=True,append_images=img1)
```

Above code resulted into `TypeError: TiffImageFile' object is not iterable.`

Can anyone please suggest a way to append two files into single file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `append_images` needs an array, try:

```
img1.save(output.tif,save_all=True,append_images=[img1])
```

Hope It helps!